# Oracle Apex error handling

Tags: oracle, error-handling, oracle-apex

I have a textbox (tb_pcode) that user must enter the personnel code. This is a part of my code :

```
   declare
      n varchar2(20);
   begin
      select name into n
      from pers e
      where e.pcode = :tb_pcode;
    exception 
    when no_data_found then
        apex_error.add_error (
        p_message          => 'No person found!',
        p_display_location => apex_error.c_inline_in_notification );
    end;
```

but this lines ignore at all and no message display.

```
    apex_error.add_error (
    p_message          => 'No person found!',
    p_display_location => apex_error.c_inline_in_notification );
```

Why?!

Comment: `apex_error.add_error` adds an error to the list of errors to be displayed the next time the page is rendered. If you put this in a dynamic action, the page is not being re-rendered so nothing gets displayed.

Comment: Thank you Jeffrey. The problem is that I have a textbox and user must enter a code. after entering the code I need a validation that runs a plsql query and if no_data_found happens, application must show a page error and then clean the textbox. There is no page render or refresh through this process. What shall I do?!

Comment: A simple way is to add a display item to show the error message, and populate it with a PL/SQL dynamic action.

Answer (score 0):

I've just tried it on Apex 5.1.1, works just fine.

Where did you put that code? I created a **validation** on the TB_PCODE text item; validation type is "PL/SQL Function (returning Error Text)".

On the other hand, one reason might be that you, actually, entered a valid code and query returned *something* (i.e. SELECT didn't raise no-data-found).

Comment: I have put this code in dynamic action of textbox ( when changed ). The query returns nothing. According to your answer I put the code in validation over textbox with "PL/SQL Function (returning Error Text)" but nothing happened. Just I give this message : ora-01403 no data found

Comment: If possible, create an example on apex.oracle.com & provide credentials so that someone of us might take a look.

Comment: By the way if I delete those three lines and put this line instead : htp.p('alert(no data found)'); This code not works too! What is the problem of this?